# Listing the raster layers on the canvas for selection by user

Tags: raster, pyqgis, layers, qgis-processing

I am creating a processing script that will take input from the user. The input parameter is to be a raster layer. Using the method described at https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/processing_python_plugin.html

which lists vector layers that are on the canvas with

```
self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )
```

However, I want to have a source of raster layers. So I am looking to do exactly what the code does, but for raster layers. I cannot find how to do this. It seems from what I have found that it is necessary to list the filenames that the rasters are stored in. Is this the case? Can I list the raster layers for selection without  doing that?
I am using QGIS 3.16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at QGIS source code to find how it is done by QGIS developers.

For instance, look at [this example](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/f32725658f205af4ac9718d3a3b74f13eaa98d3e/python/plugins/processing/algs/gdal/gdalcalc.py#L64-L67):

```
self.addParameter(
        QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer(
            self.INPUT_A,
            self.tr('Input layer A'),
            optional=False))
```

As usual, you can find the accepted arguments in the [QGIS API docs](https://qgis.org/api/3.16/classQgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer.html#a8957c15abaff7e4547765888eb91f226).

Comment: Germán, thanks, that is perfect. So now the dialog shows a list of raster layers allows the user to choose one, and then that file will be the source of the data to be processed. That was just what I wanted.

Comment: Good, then don't forget to mark the answer as accepted and, if you haven't, you can also vote up it. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Germán -  done! accepted and voted up.